# Using Material-UI Themes in ReactCSSTransitionGroup classes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Short question, how does one use `material-ui` themes in `ReactCssTransitionGroup` transitiions?

To explain further, I am using `material-ui` for my UI elements and using the `muiThemeable` HOC to inject the theme into those components that need it. This enables components to use styles from the theme.

I would now like to use a `ReactCssTransitionGroup` to animate entry and exit of elements in a group. I would like to be able to use the background and text colours defined in the `material-ui` theme (which can be changed by the user). But, `ReactCssTransitionGroup` uses CSS and I cannot access the theme when defining the CSS.

Elsewhere I have been using Aphrodite to allow me to generate CSS class names and this does enable me to use the `material-ui` theme.

As an example I have style definitions of:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    item: {
        border: '1px solid black',
        padding: 10,
        margin: 10,
        width: 400,
        background: muiTheme.primary1Color,
        color: muiTheme.textColor,
    },
    enter: {
        color: muiTheme.primary1Color,
    },
    enterActive: {
        color: muiTheme.textColor,
        transition: 'all 500ms ease-out',
    },
    leave: {
        color: muiTheme.textColor,
    },
    LeaveActive: {
        color: muiTheme.primary1Color,
        transition: 'all 500ms ease-in',
    },
});
```

And then a transition group defined by

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
    transitionName={{
        enter: css(styles.enter),
        enterActive: css(styles.enterActive),
        leave: css(styles.leave),
        leaveActive: css(styles.leaveActive),
    }}
    transitionEnterTimeout={500}
    transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
>
    {items}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

This works in as much as it generates valid CSS classes which is used by the `ReactTransitionGroup` and can be seen being added and removed from elements in the debugger. But the transitions themselves do not appear because Aphrodite does not allow one to declare child classes like `.example-enter.example-enter-active` and this is required by `ReactCssTransistionGroup` to provide a higher specificity than the CSS defined for the element.

Is there any way around this? Is there any way of creating CSS classes with the specificity required and including themed elements for use with ReactCssTransistionGroup?

Comment: Did you found a solution?